# UBUNTU Login Freeze + TTY shortcut not working

Tags: freeze, login-screen, tty

I ran into the problem of when I login in, Ubuntu freezes, I looked at the solutions, but I can’t open the tty with any of the alt cntrl fs

Comment: Can you boot to Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu?

Comment: @heynnema Yes i can, i tried to do those sudo install nvidia drivers but that didnt work..

Comment: Did you already have Nvidia drivers installed? If so, what version? What happened when you tried to install them this time? Do you know how to boot with `nomodeset`?

Comment: i got it to work, i just forgot to click enter then y then it told me to disable secure mode, and then it worked, sorry for wasting your time.....

Comment: Glad you got it working!